# Python how to pass selenium driver into function

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, headless-browser

I keep on getting this error when running my code:

```
**name 'driver' is not defined**
```

Can anybody tell me why? How would I make it run like this. So If any of the smaller tests fail, it is very clear where the problem is.

```
generateRandomBroswerInfo()
loginSite()
getSomeInfo()
quitBroswer()
```

I am using selenium on Python 3.6

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


def genrateBroswer():
    dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
    dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = ('Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A334 Safari/7534.48.3')
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=dcap)
    driver.set_window_size(300, 600)

def letssee():
    driver.get('http://www.whatsmyip.org/')
    driver.save_screenshot('this.png')


genrateBroswer()
letssee()
#ETC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a class with all the necessary methods, see [Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html). An example:

```
class Webdriver:

    def __init__(self):
        self.genrateBroswer()
        self.letssee()


    def genrateBroswer(self):
        dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
        dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = ('Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A334 Safari/7534.48.3')
        self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=dcap)
        self.driver.set_window_size(300, 600)

    def letssee(self):
        self.driver.get('http://www.whatsmyip.org/')
        self.driver.save_screenshot('this.png')


# Creating an instance of the webdriver
myWebsite = Webdriver()

myWebsite.driver
```

In short, everything you need to use across functions, you need to make a property of the class by storing it with the keyword `self`, and you need to pass `self` to all the functions in the class.

Comment: I marked your answer because it works. But it isn't the answer I fixed my problem with instead I turned my variable driver into a variable globe.

Comment: @FutureHendrixs if you want to stay away from classes, I would recommend bgse's method, by passing `driver` to the functions, and returning the updated `driver`.

Comment: Can you show how you fixed the problem by using global variable? @FutureHendrixs ? I am trying @rinkert method but still getting `driver not defined`

Answer (score 1):

**Working for me**

```
    class Class(object):

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--lang=EN')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='assets/chromedriver', chrome_options=options)

    iframe = ''

    def LogIn(self, telnum, password):
        self.driver.set_window_size(800, 600)
        self.driver.get("url")
        self.iframe = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="app"]/div/section/div[2]/div/div/iframe')
        self.driver.switch_to.frame(self.iframe)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining `driver` locally inside `genrateBroswer`, once you leave that function, it is gone.

In your `letssee` function, you are trying to access `driver`, which is not defined at this point, hence you are getting an error:

```
NameError: name 'driver' is not defined
```

For details, read about [Python variables and scope](http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html).

Also, check out [the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/).

Comment: Can I take out `driver`  from `genrateBroswer` and load it into the second function? & how

Comment: You could for example add a return statement to the end of your `genrateBroswer` function: `return driver`, and call it like `driver = genrateBroswer()`.

Comment: @FutureHendrixs On a side note, I'd suggest you work your way through [the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/), as this is kind of a very basic question. No offense meant, just it'll save you a lot of headache and swearing :-)